# Regex infitine capture groups after a specific string

Tags: python, regex

I have a bot that takes a number of different commands and I'm trying scale it's ability to take arguments for all these commands.

This is the syntax:

```
!action db_table mandatory_arg arg1 arg2 arg3...
```

Right now I have this functional but un-scalable regex for processing commands:

```
^!(\S*)\s?(\S*)\s?(\S*)\s?(\S*)\s?(\S*)\s?(\S*)\s?(\S*)\s?(\S*)$
```

It works, but it's not great and it's obviously limited to how many \S* I add in there.

So how can I match an unlimited number of arguments in the following string?

```
!dont match this match1 match2 match3 match4 etc...
```

I've tried using a lookbehind but it only works for the first match. I've also tried making it [^ignore] the first part completely but again, this only works for the first argument since the others are also looking for that specific ignore.

Finally, I also gave \K a shot but it didn't work out.

```
!\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\K(\S*)*
```

Comment: Why not use `.split()` ?

Comment: Are you using PyPi regex library?

Comment: Regex can't capture an unlimited number of strings. Why don't you just split your string on whitespace?

Comment: Why not do something like this: [`(?<=^!|\s)(\S*)`](https://regex101.com/r/pMlkUy/1)? Btw, `\K` is not available in python: it matches a literal `K`.

Comment: Quake, please post your current code.

Comment: I'd actually suggest editing my regex above to be `(?<=^!|\s)(\S+)` instead (in case there are multiple spaces). Just note that it will incorrectly match a string that begins with spaces, so you'd have to combine it with a string function that removes whitespaces from the start of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to need to grab space separated arguments after a specific pattern from the beginning of a string. You may capture any 1+ chars after that pattern, run a `re.search`/`re.match` to grab that value, and once a match is found, just `split()` the `match.group(1)`.

The regex will turn out to be

```
^!\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+(.+)
```

Or, to shorten it a bit:

```
^!(?:\w+\s+){3}(.+)
```

Note that `^` will be redundant in `re.match` where the pattern is anchored at the beginning of the string by default. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MvEqcW/2).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WsBsGn):

```
import re
rx = r"!\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+(.+)"
s = "!action db_table mandatory_arg arg1 arg2 arg3"
m = re.match(rx, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1).split())
# => ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

Comment: That's good. I'm still learning Regex and I was hoping to make everything work in a single search, without using Python to clean up afterwards but I'll take your answer.

Comment: @Quake If you install PyPi regex module, you may do everything with 1 regex, see [**this demo**](http://rextester.com/AAWW31809). If my answer works for you best, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no regex needed here, just use `split()`:

```
cmds = ['!action db_table mandatory_arg arg1 arg2 arg3...', 
        '!dont match this match1 match2 match3 match4 etc...', 
        'this one not']

new_cmds = [args[3:]
            for cmd in cmds
            for args in [cmd.split()]
            if cmd.startswith('!')]

print(new_cmds)
# [['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3...'], 
#  ['match1', 'match2', 'match3', 'match4', 'etc...']]
```